# Fragment not updating listview

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a fragment and in it there are three tabhosts. Each of them is a fragment on its own. Lets call them A,B,C. Then from Fragment C I start an activity using startactivityonresult:-

```
public class FavCommittee extends Fragment {
    public ArrayList<Committee> favCommitteeData = new ArrayList<>();

    @Nullable
    @Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        favCommitteeData.clear();
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.house, container, false);
        Context cont = getActivity();
        final SharedPreferences pref = getContext().getSharedPreferences("MyFav", 0);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        Map<String,?> entries = pref.getAll();
        final Set<String> keys = entries.keySet();
        int count=0;
        for (String key:keys) {
            String val = pref.getString(key, null);
            String[] store = val.split(":");
            if (store[0].equals("committee"))
                count=count+1;
        }
        int max=0;
        for (String k:keys){
            String val = pref.getString(k,null);
            if(val!=null)
                max=Integer.parseInt(k);
        }
        for (int i=0;i<max+1;i++) {
            String val = pref.getString(Integer.toString(i), null);
            if (val != null) {
                String[] store = val.split(":");
                if (store[0].equals("committee")) {
                    count = count - 1;
                    new GetAllCommittees(getContext(), rootView).execute(store[1], Integer.toString(count));
                }
            }
        }        final ListView yourListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.house_listview);
        yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                Committee obj = (Committee)yourListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(FavCommittee.this.getActivity(), committee_info.class);
                intent.putExtra("Committee",obj.getCommittee_id());
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
```

In the activity I close the activity in the following way:-

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
        finish();
    }
```

Now in fragment C again I have implemented onActivityResult() like this:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        getActivity();
        if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d("Called Again",Integer.toString(favCommitteeData.size()));
        }
```

The thing is onActivityResult is not called after the activity closes. Can someone help me figure why?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you haven't set a breakpoint on your `onActivityResult` in `FragmentC`. The issue is this: I just basically made the same situation in my own project, and onActivityResult is called, but the resultCode is `Activity.RESULT_CANCELLED`. That is because you still have `super.onBackPressed()` in your overridden `onBackPressed()` in your activity, and it's setting the result to CANCELLED regardless of what happens after that.

So the simple answer is remove the super.onBackPressed() from your overridden `onBackPressed()` method in your activity, and it should go through just fine.

Comment: There is no activity...Fragment C is just inside another fragment

Comment: I actually found the problem otherwise. I've edited my answer accordingly.